# Email no longer sent after jenkins job execution

Tags: jenkins, ubuntu-16.04, jenkins-email-ext

On a Ubuntu, I have a Jenkins service setup with Email-EXT plugin, where I have setup jobs executed regularly, and emails are being sent after the job execution. But just recently, I no longer receive any emails after the job execution.

Details:

- In each job execution "console output", it is said that Email has been triggered.
- And I was able to use the "Test configuration by sending test e-mail"
  on Jenkins/"configure system" page" to send out the testing email.
- Based on my company rule, I had the password changed just recently.
  And I did the some update on jenkins/configure page as well.
- jenkins version 2.176.1
- EMAIL-EXT plugin version: 2.69

So what could be wrong for not receiving emails ????

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there is nothing wrong with the jenkins side settings. I have switched the smtp server to user the gmail one, and it works. It must be some policy change on my company smtp server side.

BTW, to turn on the debug mode of the trigger gives some direction to my case.